# Symfony error on login page on implement UserLoaderInterface

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I am using symfony version 5.4.4., and the first page of my application is a login page, but when I load it, I get this error:

> You must either make the "App\Entity\mUser" entity Doctrine Repository
> ("App\Repository\mUserRepository") implement
> "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface" or set the
> "property" option in the corresponding entity provider configuration.]

Whats causing this error?

Comment: Incomplete [`security.yaml` configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#entity-user-provider).

Comment: @yivi yes, i find a solution. I add the "implements UserLoaderInterface" to my "mUserRepository" class, and create a "loadUserByUsername" method that return null and it works. Soon i will increase the method, but this just solve my problem. Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony does not know how to get the users from the Doctrine repository.

The error is pretty explicit about what you need to do.

You have two options:

Either you change your existing user repository (`App\Repository\mUserRepository`) so it implements the `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface`

The interface has only one method:

```
public function loadUserByUsername(string $username);
```

So you'd need to do something like:

```
class App\Repository\mUserRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername(string $username): ?UserInterface
    {
       // implement logic to get user from the repository by its username.
    }
}
```

Note that if you check that interface, the method `loadUserByUsername()` is actually deprecated, and has been replaced by `loadUserByIdentifier()` in Symfony 6+. To future-proof your implementation you should have something like:

```
class App\Repository\mUserRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername(string $username): ?UserInterface
    {
       return $this->loadUserByIdentifier($username);
    }

    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier): ?UserInterface
    {
       // implement logic to get user from the repository by its username.
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, the error message is telling you to just configure which property you use as identifier for your users.

Let's say that you get them by email, and there is an `mUser::email` property.

```yaml
providers:
        mUserProvider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\mUser
                property: email
```